# Win 10 Pro lanmanserver - prevent binding to interface

Tags: windows, network-share, ssh-tunnel, truenas

**Motivation:**

I am trying to proxy SMB connections through an SSH tunnel to a remote network, using either PuTTY, Bitvise SSH client, or similar.

This works well with other services, such as HTTP(S).

In order to avoid disabling SMB on the current interface, be it a Wi-Fi, or cabled device, I chose to setup a loopback adapter and binding the tunnel's listener to it.

```
Loopback adapter
`-- SSH Tunnel listening on port 445
    `-- SSH to remote host
        `-- Proxy to FreeNAS file server, port 445
```

Then, opening explorer.exe and accessing loopback adapter's IP address, or its equivalent local lmhosts entry, should proxy traffic to/from the remote FreeNAS file server via the tunnel.

```
\\192.168.0.2 or
\\freenas
```

**Problem:**

The local port binding attempt by the reverse SSH tunnel fails, because lanmanserver listens on all interfaces by default.

Running the below command shows that it is indeed listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0).

```
netstat -ano | findstr 445
```

**Attempted Solution:**

After many hours of searching, I discovered this post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/559e983a-3a53-4ad2-8030-b0cfc9ed0813/how-to-disable-tcpip-and-filesharing-service-on-interface

In order to find out the loopback interface's GUID, I used the very useful ShareFix script:

https://github.com/filippobottega/ShareFix

I then proceeded to remove all entries matching the corresponding GUID, from the *bind* key.

Once complete, I rebooted.

Unfortunately, lanmanserver was still listening on all interfaces.

**Question:**

What else should be done to prevent lanmanserver from binding to that specific interface?

Have I omitted something critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the following on Microsoft's site:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/204279/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcp-ip

> NetbiosSmb is a global device, and is not bound on a per-adapter basis. This means that direct-hosted SMB's cannot be disabled in Windows without disabling File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks completely.

**Solution:** (at time of writing)

Disable lanmanserver:

https://winaero.com/blog/disable-service-windows-10/

This is probably not such a travesty after all, particularly if your Windows clients only need to access SMB shares on a central server.

It might be useful if someone with a deep knowledge of Windows and its design choices, might explain why it's all, or nothing?

I've read possibly spurious statements that disabling lanmanserver can result in "undesirable consequences". Please do share.

Comment: I'd like to clarify, that I didn't use this solution in the end. The workstations had been using ProxyCap to successfully tunnel SMB over SSH to a remote site, but then spontaneously (after upgrading ProxyCap) stopped working. After days of tinkering, leading to the above attempt, it turned out that I had to downgrade ProxyCap back to version 5.29 http://www.proxycap.com/update/pcap529_x64.msi - Newer releases do not support proxying NetBIOS & SMB. At the time of writing this, the vendor had neither notified its paid customers, nor published such a fundamental feature removal on their website.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable SMB on a network interface, go to the interface's properties and disable "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks":

[image]

Comment: Thanks @massimo, but that does not resolve it. Lanmanserver continues to bind to an interface, even with that option unchecked.